# How can I get count of similar items records from list in SharePoint hosted app?

Tags: jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created SharePoint Hosted app.

I have list called **Likes** it contains item records.

I have custom columns called **Ids** it hold the another list item id **ID**.

[image]

Using JSOM in SharePoint Hosted app, I'm trying to get count of Similar **Ids** columns value.

Example: In the list there are some records having **Ids** is 6 and their count is 3.

Comment: How many items (records) do you plan to store in this list (roughly)?

Comment: I'm planning to store more than 500 records

Comment: "more than 500 records", but less than...?

Answer (score 7):

If I am not wrong, you want to group the list item with the column ids as displayed in the below image:

[image: Highlighted area displays the count]

In order to achieve this, please follow the following link:
https://piyushksingh.com/2016/11/21/retrieve-grouped-listitems-sharepoint/
So in this link, both **CSOM** and **JSOM** code snippets are available.

Answer (score 5):

The only possible option seems that you have to write some tricky codes. Follow the below steps:

- Write JSOM and Get all items in JavaScript Array.
- Apply Group By functionality
- Count the Similar items
- Display the count.

For group by and counting using JavaScript, you can refer [How do I do a array group and count it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26323543/777171)